# ¿Cuál es el significado de “tres y repique” en este pasaje?

Tags: expresiones, significado

Leyendo la novela *La barraca* de Ibáñez me encontré con la siguiente oración:

> Era su marcha una enrevesada peregrinación por las calles, deteniéndose ante las puertas cerradas; un aldabonazo aquí, **tres y repique** más allá, y siempre, á continuación, el grito estridente y agudo, que parecía imposible pudiese surgir de su pobre y raso pecho: «¡La lleeet!»

Las dos acepciones de la palabra “repique” que figuran en el DRAE no parecen encajar en el contexto. Además, tengo la impresión de que “tres y repique” es (o fue) una frase hecha, pero no he llegado a descubrir su significado.

Comment: En Project Gutenberg hay una versión en inglés.  Quién sabe si está bien la traducción, pero da "three or more repeated raps" (tocando en las puertas).

Comment: @aparente001 Había consultado esa traducción, que solo sirvió para aumentar mi perplejidad. O el traductor no logró interpretar bien el sentido de la frase castellana, o decidió traducirla de manera muy libre.

Comment: Gallego - encontré varias otras ideas, pero no llego aún a una solución.  Parece que en América Latina quiere decir que la persona no tiene dinero, pero eso no viene al caso.  "Tres" quizás se refiere al group estándar de tres tambores.  Yo sospecho que es un ritmo definido (análogo al "Shave and a haircut -- two bits").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que no se trata de ninguna frase hecha. Yo entiendo el texto como:

> Un aldabonazo aquí, tres [aldabonazos] y repique más allá...

Es decir, que en algunas casas pegaba un aldabonazo, y en otras tres aldabonazos más un [repique](https://dle.rae.es/?id=W1wz8BU) de campana (de las que colgaban en las casas para llamar). Tanto las aldabas como las campanas eran objetos que se añadían a las puertas de las viviendas para poder anunciar la presencia de un visitante.

Buscando en el NTLLE no encuentro ninguna frase hecha del estilo de "tres y repique". Pero sí que parece que era una forma de llamar, a juzgar por este texto unas décadas anterior al tuyo:

> *Llegamos a la puerta de su casa; bajé del coche; llamé al portón (tres y repique); abrieron; [...].*
>
> Pedro Antonio de Alarcón, "Relatos", 1852 - 1882 (España).

Comment: Ahora me queda más claro. Quizás en aquella época había dos maneras habituales de llamar a la puerta (un aldabonazo o tres aldabonazos más un repique de campana). A los lectores de aquel entonces tales costumbres les resultarían familiares y por eso no haría falta una descripción más extensa.